# What is principle of Spark sample method with replacement?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am studing Spark, and I have a question about sample() method..
As you might know, sample() take three parameters

`sample( withReplacement : boolean, Fraction : Double, seed : Long )`

I can't understand second one `fraction` when withReplacement is True.

In Document, it means expected value of each element's replacement extraction.

If I input 2 in fraction and RDD has 10 elements, how does It sample inside? What is the principle? ( I know It doesn't guarantee sampling amount of 20)

Please help me understand.

Answer (score 4):

To achieve sampling with replacement Spark [is using `PoissonSampler`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f856fe4839757e3a1036df3fc3dec459fa439aef/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L512). It generates numbers from [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) to determine how many items sampler should skip, before yielding a new value.

The higher the fraction, the lower the lambda parameter of the Poisson distribution or in other words, the higher the probability the step will 0, and we take the same item again.

[image: Poisson distribution depending on lambda]

Image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#/media/File:Poisson_pmf.svg) by [Skbkekas](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=User:Skbkekas&action=edit&redlink=1).

Please refer to the [sampler source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2977e2312d9690c9ced3c86b0ce937819e957775/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/random/RandomSampler.scala#L188) to see the exact procedure.